# Wireshark: how to show UDP payload as text?

Tags: wireshark, udp

I have a device that *broadcasts* strings for debugging purposes, and i need to capture these UDP message and read the string.

[image: Actual Data screenshot]

As you can see, i cannot read anything in the **data.text** column, while the **data.data** show the ASCII values of the string characters (the string sent from the device is "0123456789").

How can i read the payload as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Data dissector preference for "Show data as text" under: Edit > Preferences > Protocols > Data

[image]

and then use the field `data.text` as your column.

(per [link](https://ask.wireshark.org/question/18978/column-format/))